# Java concurrency lock and condition usage

Tags: java

I can use `object.wait` ,`object.notify` and `synchronized blocks` to solve the producer consumer type of problems. At the same time I can use `locks` and `conditions` from `java.util.concurrent` package. I am sure I am not able to understand why we need conditions when we can use `object.wait` and `notify` to make threads waiting on some condition like queue is empty or full. Is there any other benefit we are getting if we use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/) provides a good explanation:

> Just as Lock is a generalization for
>   synchronization, the Lock framework
>   includes a generalization of wait and
>   notify called Condition. A Lock object
>   acts as a factory object for condition
>   variables bound to that lock, and
>   unlike with the standard wait and
>   notify methods, there can be more than
>   one condition variable associated with
>   a given Lock.

Comment: link dead ->the IBM developerWorks Web site is currently under maintenance.