# Notifying a single thread: notify, notifyAll or concurrent.locks.Condition?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I need to wake up or send to sleep a **single** Thread sometimes, and I'm wondering what is the best and most efficient way to do it.

The first solution is signaling combined with `wait-notify` (I know how to implement this pattern properly, that's not the question).

I read it somewhere that using the *java.concurrent* library and `CountDownLatch` for signaling is more efficient. I checked [concurrent.locks.Condition](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) as well, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953556/1099432) topic states that it's merely a (programmer-wise) more safe and generalized construct, without a performance benefit compared to `notify/notifyAll`. Peter Lawrey recommends using the *Concurrency* library instead of `notify-notifyAll` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026/java-notify-vs-notifyall-all-over-again) comment, so now I'm confused what is the best practice to use.

A related question: which is better performance-wise, `notify` or `notifyAll` in my case (i.e. if I have one thread)? I know there are lot of similar threads about this, but none of them give a clear answer. In my case, functionally, it doesn't matter which I use, but I wonder which is faster, then.

Comment: I would half-blindly trust Peter Lawrey's suggestions, almost always.

Comment: I would only do so if the logical arguments (pro, contra) are balanced or if the problem is empirical and cannot be analytically approached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO they don't make much difference "performance-wise" since they all suspend the thread calling the corresponding `wait` so most likely the underlying mechanisms are very similar. And why would performance matter so much anyway? Unless you have some extremely fast wait/signal pattern in which the signal comes **immediately** after the wait, making a context-switch too expensive and requiring perhaps a spinlock instead, there's no need to worry about performance.

You should implement what you think is the most convenient method programming-wise and then benchmark and see if you really need something more performant.

Comment: I would go with notify/notifyAll then, but one question remains: for signaling one Thread, which is more efficient? This would require knowing how the JVM is implemented for them. I know the difference is negligible, but preferring one to the other requires no plus optimization work (because I either write "notify" or "notifyall"), so I would like to use the "theoretically" better solution (since there is no reason not to do so).

Comment: @Thomas Calc: How often do you expect to use these mechanisms in you app?

Comment: It depends on the user input, to be general. In worst case, once per second.

Comment: @Thomas Calc: I was browsing over the source codes but it's hard to tell which is more efficient from there because it eventually jumps into native methods. You'll just have to search for a benchmark of these mechanisms or do one yourself. However, even at one signal/second I still maintain that the difference won't matter.

Comment: If there is any difference, it certainly is sub-millisecond so if it happens once per second, there clearly is no point worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

`wait-notify` is perfectly fine.

since there's only one thread on the waiting list, there's no difference, semantics or performance wise, between `notify` and `notifyAll`.